# styling of h2 in the previous section applied to non-descendant sections

Tags: html, css

I have several sections in html, so I styled h1 for the first section like so:

```
.banner-inner h1 {
color: yellow;
font-size: 2.8rem;
font-weight: 400;
padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Strangely, the styling was also applied to next sections, and even the footer. 
How is this possible, if those section and the footer are not descendants of .banner-inner?
(I'm just beginning to learn css, so excuse me if my question is too simple)

Comment: you need to show the relevant html (*one that exhibits the problem*)

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? Or maybe send us the link to your website if it is live? Or create an example for us either using StackOverflow snippets or JSFiddle, please and thanks!

Comment: classes can be applied to more than one element - sounds like your other sections (or a parent element that contains all of them) also have the `.banner-inner` class?

Answer (score 0):

use tag name before using class name if you have same class name in other element then it will apply same effect
if class name is different then your above css script is corret

```
 div.banner-inner h1 {
      color: yellow;
      font-size: 2.8rem;
      font-weight: 400;
      padding-top: 5px;
    }
```